# SSIS - Send email when task of a package fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, email-notifications

I have a package in Sql Server 2012. I develop this package with SSIS tools. I’m trying to generate an email in case one of the task fails but the package finish successfully. I want to do it from SQL side, no inside the package.

Thanks

Juan

Comment: How are you calling the package?

Comment: im calling inside a job